# Does Rebol run well on Raspberry Pi and BeagleBoard?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rebol, beagleboneblack

Are Rebol language implementations small enough to run on cheap experimenter boards like the Raspberry Pi or the BeagleBone? Can it control outputs and GPIO?

Comment: Small enough? yes. Control outputs and GPIO? Probably, though device files.

Answer (score 4):

Rebol 3 runs well on the Raspberry Pi and I believe it also runs on a BeagleBone.

Use the rebolsource Linux ARMhf build from http://rebolsource.net/

I have not tried using the GPIO functions of the Raspberry Pi yet, but if there is a block device you can read and write to it should be trivial from Rebol.

Answer (score 4):

I run Rebol 3 on the Raspberry Pi all the time.  There is more than enough power to run it.  I also wrote a GPIO dialect for Rebol 3 that you can read about in the August 2014 issue of ODROID Magazine (http://magazine.odroid.com) and download from a link in that article.  The GPIO dialect was specifically written for ODROID, but could be easily modified for the Raspberry Pi.